# Error when installing PHPUnit 'unknown channel "pear.phpunit.de" in "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit"'

Tags: php, linux

Error when installing `PHPUnit` unknown channel `pear.phpunit.de` in `pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit` invalid package name/package file "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit" on `Debian-4` OS.

I've followed instructions as per the instructions contained at http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/installation.html and I've tried the `PHAR` method and the `PEAR` method, but neither are working.

Here's the server set up:

```
PEAR Version: 1.9.4

PHP Version: 5.4.4-14+deb7u3

Zend Engine Version: 2.4.0

Running on: Linux lsh1001 3.9.6-hw+ #6 SMP
```

WHen I try to install using the `PEAR` method, I run:

```
pear config-set auto_discover 1
```

and I receive

```
config-set succeeded
```

However, when I run

```
pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

and I receive:

```
Attempting to discover channel "pear.phpunit.de"...
downloading channel.xml ...
Starting to download channel.xml (804 bytes)
....done: 804 bytes
Auto-discovered channel "pear.phpunit.de", alias "pear.phpunit.de", adding to registry
unknown channel "pear.phpunit.de" in "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit"
invalid package name/package file "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit"
install failed
```

I'm new to using the command line prompt so I may be doing something strange. I've tried prefixing the lines of code with **sudo**, but I receive:

```
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

when I do this.

I want to be able to run `PHPUnit` using the browser front-end rather than the command line install. I also tried the `PHAR` install method, but I'm not sure how to point to the installed `phpunit.phar` file. I can run the `phpunit.phar` file straight from the command line, but how would I refer to it in my `php.ini` file? I have left the file in my root directory and haven't moved it.

Answer (score 4):

try this command flow

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de

pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

and... if you are `root` ignore `sudo`

Reffer  [PHPUnit Site](http://pear.phpunit.de/)